# Black screen, no grub, dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, nvidia, uefi

I have just installed the latest version of Ubuntu from a USB alongside  Windows 10.

I am unable to boot into Ubuntu.  I get a black screen. Neither Esc nor Shift will cause the grub menu to load.

It may be something silly as I am new to linux but I can't figure it out.

I am using an Nvidia graphics card, which I have found from other forum posts to be an issue. However, all the solutions seem to require being able to get to the grub menu in order to change the boot mode which I can't do.

I tried running Disk Repair from the USB but that didn't make any difference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting the boot partition from the BIOS/UEFI menu if your motherboard supports this feature. You can usually do this after the POST beep by pressing `F12`. This should give you access to Ubuntu's TTY at the least so that you can properly install the NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I can't get to the TTY either. If I set the boot partition to ubuntus then press F12 after the BIOS screen I still get a black screen. With a 'dd' Q code on my motherboard (ASUS maximus heo alpha VIII)

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get through, finally. After unnecessarily removing my graphics card and reinstalling Ubuntu.

It was changing secure boot mode from windows -> other OS in my BIOS. I hadn't even intended for it to be in secure boot mode, ought to have noticed.

Hopefully that will be a useful thing to try if anyone runs into the same issue in the future.